# how to filter posts by category without page load (ajax) in wordpress?

Tags: posts, categories, filters, ajax

I Tried this code, here: http://rankonone.com/dev/profdharm/monthly-rashifal/

August, October, September are categories, I want to show post below without page load where currently title and date.

Can anyone please help?

```
//This is category filter: 
<ul class="xiong-filters">
<?php 
      //This one is to display All in your category.
      // Do not use show_option_all parameter since it includes all categories not just one your displaying
      $args= array(  
        'include'          =>   2, //Put here ID of your category
        'title_li'          => __('')
      );
    wp_list_categories( $args );
  ?>
  <?php 
      //This one displays subcategories of your category
      $args= array(  
        'child_of'          =>   2, //Put here parent category
        'title_li'          => __('')
      );
    wp_list_categories( $args );
  ?>
```

```
<!--Post LOOP  -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) :?>
  <div id="main-content" class="row">
    <div id="inside">
      <div class="container">

  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <article>
<a class="xiong-articlebox" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
    <header>
        <h3><?php the_title( );?></h3>
        <p><em><?php the_date( 'j.n.Y'); ?> </em></p>

        </header>
         <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
       </a>
   </article>

  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


</div><!-- container-->
```

```
//AJAX Filters
jQuery(function(){
var mainContent = jQuery('#main-content'),
    cat_links = jQuery('ul.xiong-filters li a');

    cat_links.on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        el = $(this);
        var value = $el.attr("href");
        mainContent.animate({opacity:"0.5"});
        mainContent.load(value + " #inside", function(){
            mainContent.animate({opacity:"1"});
        });
        jQuery( "li" ).removeClass( "current-cat" );
         jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass("current-cat");
    });
});


//Function.php
//ENQUEUE SCRIPTS HERE
function xiong_theme_scripts() {
//Ajax filter scripts
wp_register_script( 'ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js',
array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax' );}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'xiong_theme_scripts' );
```

Comment: Where is your AJAX call? You have an error in your jQuery file. ```$el``` should be ```el```.

Comment: @moped  thanks for comment sir, can you give me hint for AJAX call. I copied that code from somewhere. Please help

Comment: Well, if you have nothing yet, it will be too much to hint. One possible way: Your AJAX call will be in your jQuery click event, which posts the category id to an action where you query like in your category filter. Then you add the result of this query in an html block, which echoes your filter action back to the AJAX success function and jQuery adds the new html into your page.